# Duplicate question - As the user asking the question what do I do?

Tags: support, questions, answers, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

A question of mine has been marked as a duplicate. The one my question has in fact got an answer which also answers mine.

What do I need to do in order to accept the relevant answer as valid for my question? What do the rules of community require in cases like this?

Comment: upvote the answer who helped you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[The UI that's being used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/175248) only allows you to mark your question as a duplicate.  That's all the acceptance that needs to be done in this scenario.

Outside of that, upvoting the answer that helped you the most would be ideal.